# How to display multilingual or any UNICODE special character in itextpdf PDF which is accepted from UI?

Tags: java, itext

How i can diplay **multiligual and mathamatical symbols** in java **itextpdf** PDF?

I have tried **arialuni.ttf** in BaseFont,

But still Some Mathematical symbols are not shows in itextpdf.

Please help for this, I want exact text content accepted from web application wanted to show in itextpdf.

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Şinasi ıssız ile ağaç", new Font(bf, 22));

document.add(p);
```

Comment: Any **unicode font type** which is exact used by web browsers.

Comment: Apparently your copy of arialuni.ttf simply does not contain the required glyphs. I ran your code using the current Windows 10 c:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB6zi.png), all your characters present.